# equivalence in callback and non-callback javascript

Tags: javascript, programming-practices, coding-style

I'm pretty sure that the following two snippets are equivalent but I wanted to double check:

**CALLBACK STYLE**

```
function foo(input, callback) {
    // do stuff with input

    callback();
}

function bar(input, callback) {
    // do stuff with input

    callback();
}

foo("hi", bar("bye", function() {
                       // do something cool
                     }));
```

*Note that the callbacks take no arguments.*

**PLAIN STYLE**

```
function foo(input) {
    // do stuff with input
}

function bar(input) {
    // do stuff with input
}

foo("hi");
bar("bye");
(function() {
    // do something cool
})();
```

Of course if they are equivalent it would make sense to me to use **PLAIN STYLE** as it's simpler and cleaner.

I realize the scope of the anonymous function (who does something cool) is different in the two cases.. I'm not concerned with that aspect of "equivalence".

**UPDATE**

I'm working on some legacy code and find quite a bit of it confusing. This is the original code that prompted this question. Specifically the noted 6 or so lines of code.

```
var CoolNamespace = (function () {
    var container_element,
        keysLength = 0;

    //
    // THE FOLLOWING 6 OR SO LINES IS WHAT I'M CURIOUS ABOUT
    //
    _createCoolObject(function (coolObject) {
        _appendFrameToContainer(coolObject, function () {

            // Post form
            _sendForm(function (form) {
                container_element.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();
            });
        }); 
    });

    function _sendForm (callback) {
        // Sends client data via post.
        if (keysLength != 0) {
            var form = _createForm();
        } else {
            throw new Error("error message stub");
        }
        callback(form);
    }

    function _appendFrameToContainer (frame, callback) {
        if (typeof container_element != "undefined") {
            container_element.appendChild(frame);
        } else {
            throw new Error("error message stub");
        }
        callback();
    }

    function _createCoolObject (callback) {
        var coolObject = { level: "very cool" };

        callback(coolObject);
    }

    function _handleMessage (event) {
        // it's not really about this function
    }

    function _createForm() {
        // it's not really about this function either
        var form;
        return form;
    }
})();
```

When stepping through the code, it seemed to be the case that the body of `_createCoolObject` was invoked *before* the argument (which is a function). I think my confusion was that a the argument to `_createCoolObject` is a function literal which evaluates to a function but that function *is not itself evaluated* until the line `callback(coolObject)`. Thanks for the clarification!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not equivalent in their execution order.

```
foo("hi", bar("bye", function() {
    // do something cool
}));
```

This must first evaluate `bar("bye", function() { … })`, then calls `foo("hi", …)` with the result of that invocation. As the return value of `bar` is `undefined`, you'll get an error when you call that as a function.

If you want the callback example to be equivalent to your plain example, you'd have to do:

```
foo("hi", function() {
    return bar("bye", function () {
        // do something cool
    });
});
```

I would also change the definition of `foo` and `bar` so that they do `return callback()`, which allows for more general code.

Notice that this callback style is similar – but not equivalent – to [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Comment: So maybe I had the order wrong - For the **PLAIN EXAMPLE** would it have been equivalent if I had written: `(function() { \\ do something cool })();` followed by `bar("bye");` followed by `foo("hi");`? (that is, if I inverted the order of the function calls)

Comment: @arigold No. For starters, your callback example produces an error because you want to call `undefined` as a function. So the equivalent plain code would be `bar("bye"); (function(){ … })(); undefined();`

Comment: What's `undefined` in the callback example?

Comment: @arigold The return value of `bar()`, which will be passed into `foo()` as its second argument.

Comment: @arigold `undefined` is a special value in JavaScript. It's the value unassigned variables have, and the return value of functions without an explicit `return`. It is similar to `null` in its semantics. [Read more in the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: Thanks - I know what `undefined` is I just didn't realize (duh) that bar returns `undefined` (the default without an explicit return statement). I can fix that by adding a `return true` in bar.